# cross platform app UX Design tips

Tags: android, ios, cordova, user-experience

I'm building an app to run on ios and android, and using phonegap as the framework.  Handling the technical issues is no problem.

But each platform has some UX differences on sizes, where things go, etc. I haven't been able to find any tips, cheatsheets, etc for laying things out on the two platforms.  An easy example (it's right at the top) is left justifying versus centering the title, another is supporting a back button from a detail view.

With so much work being done on cross platform development, it seems like someone has to have compiled tips, cheatsheets and other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The best tip I can give you is this:

Buy an Android and iPhone and use the same apps on both of them on and off. Instagram, Snapchat, etc. and see how those companies handled the issue of having consistent UIs and functionality.

Sometimes things are similar but other times Android/iPhone users will expect different functionality. The only way you will be able to really know what that is is by using both platforms yourself.

Then you can decide accordingly.

I am not aware of any hybrid cross-platform "cheatsheet" because each platform has their own design guidelines.